# How does mongodb support sorting over multiple keys?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Sorting on `Key1` first and then `Key2` isn't the same as sorting on `Key2` first then `Key1`. Mongodb just receives sort order object like `{"key1":-1, "key2":1}`.

How does it guarantee it does what the programmer wants?

There are many bindings to the mongodb driver where many programming languages have some kind of hashmap implemented, and they are likely to not reserve key order. If one uses some kind of hashmap to talk to the mongodb driver, how is the sorting key precedence by the order of insertion of keys into such hashmap guaranteed?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know there's no way to force mongodb's comparison for the sort to use a specific comparator expression. Sorting happens as follows

> When comparing values of different BSON types, MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest:
>
> 1. MinKey (internal type)
> 2. Null
> 3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles)
> 4. Symbol, String
> 5. Object
> 6. Array
> 7. BinData
> 8. ObjectId
> 9. Boolean
> 10. Date
> 11. Timestamp
> 12. Regular Expression
> 13. MaxKey (internal type)